# Android NDK undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm migrating to cocos2d-x 3.17.2 from cocos2d-x 3.9 and when I build android studio project, I have errors when linking Wwise libAuroPannerMixer.a. NDK version 19.2, compile with clang, wwise version 2017.1.3.6377. Maybe someone has the same problem?

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := c++_static

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 - 
fsigned-char -Wno-extern-c-compat
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic -stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++

APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
APP_SHORT_COMMANDS := true

ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
  APP_OPTIM := debug
else
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
  APP_OPTIM := release
endif
```

**build.gradle:**

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.bio.brick.breaker"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 55
        versionName "1.55"
        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
                ndkBuild {
                    targets 'BioBrickBreaker'
                    arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang'
                    arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

                    def module_paths =     [project.file("../../cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                    project.file("../../cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                    project.file("../../cocos2d/external").absolutePath]
                    if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
                        module_paths = module_paths.collect {it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')}
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                    }
                    else {
                        arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
                cmake {
                    targets 'BioBrickBreaker'
                    arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        jniLibs.srcDir "libs"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'ndk-build') {
            ndkBuild {
                path "jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        else if (PROP_BUILD_TYPE == 'cmake') {
            cmake {
                path "../../CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }

            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                   arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                }
            }
       }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

    maven {
        url "http://maven.gameanalytics.com/release"
    }

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs-aar'
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    delete "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}"

    variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/../../../Resources"
            into "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}"
            exclude "**/*.gz"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
    implementation project(':downloader_library')
    implementation project(':license_library')
    implementation project(':zip_library')
}
```

**Output log:**

```
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(AuroPannerMixer.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `LssAuroPannerEncoder::setSourceParameter(char const*, float)':
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:627: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:628: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `LssAuroPannerEncoder::setSourceParameter(char const*, float)':
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:632: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:636: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:640: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:644: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:648: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o):C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:652: more undefined references to `std::string::compare(char const*) const' follow
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(AuroPannerMixer.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `LssAuroPannerEncoder::setSourceParameter(char const*, float)':
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:627: undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:628: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:240: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x\bits/basic_string.h:249: undefined reference to `std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `LssAuroPannerEncoder::setSourceParameter(char const*, float)':
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:632: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:636: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:640: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:644: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:648: undefined reference to `std::string::compare(char const*) const'
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o):C:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\Partners\Auro\AuroPanner\SoundEnginePlugin\Android/../../../auro-commons/audio/LSSAuroPanner/Src/LSSAuroPanner.cpp:652: more undefined references to `std::string::compare(char const*) const' follow
D:/dev/biobrickbreaker/proj.android/app/jni/../../../WwiseLib/android-21_arm64-v8a/Release/lib/libAuroPannerMixer.a(LSSAuroPanner.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: With `-stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++` you tell the system to use both the Clang `libc++` *and* the GCC `stdlibc++` libraries. Pick one or the other (and if you go with the Clang `libc++` then you need to add that flag when compiling as well).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I already try to use only -stdlib=libc++ but still have that errors

Comment: Did you remember to add `-stdlib=libc++` to `APP_CPPFLAGS` as well? Otherwise Clang might use the header for the GCC standard library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, same error

Comment: Also, I try to include `libc++abi.a` and `libc++_static.a` manually by adding them to Android.mk but it not fixed errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least three problems.

```
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic -stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++
```

Delete this whole line. The first flag is redundant (it's automatic with ndk-build), and the second two are wrong.

ndk-build manually links the standard library at the correct place in the link command and uses `-nostdlib++` to inhibit the compiler's default behavior. Adding `-stdlib=libc++` breaks that, so now it is being linked twice and in the wrong location.

`-lstdc++` links the wrong library.

```
c:\jenkins\ws\wwise_v2017.1\wwise\sdk\source\build\android\android-21_arm64-v8a\include\c++\4.9.x/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
```

Note specifically the path and the name of the `std` namespace here. `include\c++\4.9.x` is the path for the gnustl headers, and `std` is the name of the gnustl namespace. libc++ uses a different header path and the namespace is `std::__ndk1` (the second part is an inline namespace so that's an implementation detail you don't need to worry about when coding, but it breaks at build time to protect you from exactly these issues). Your wwise library was built with gnustl and you're using libc++. These two libraries are not compatible and cannot be used in the same application.

You need to rebuild wwise with libc++ to use it with libc++. If you're unable to do so, you need to revert to NDK r17 (the last release that supported gnustl). Note that by doing so you'll also lose access to C++14 and some pieces of C++11 (as well as reintroduce any bugs that we've fixed since then), so it's strongly preferable to rebuild wwise rather than use an old NDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `libAuroPannerMixer.a` is built incorrectly. In next wwise versions have no Auro libraries. As a result, I just remove that lib from the project and it works for me without any sound troubles. I create a topic [topic](https://www.audiokinetic.com/qa/5939/android-undefined-reference-ios_base-libauropannermixer) on wwise forum.